# OrientDb Teleporter Configuration

Tags: configuration, orientdb, rdbms

I Have 4 RDBMS tables:

```
Audience { Id, UserName }
AudienceRel { SenderId, ReceiverId, EmailId }
Email { Id, FolderId }
Folder { Id, Path }
```

I need a teleporter configuration like this:

1. A relation between Audiences by the AudienceRel table from sender Audience to Receiver audience.
2. A `FileSetId` property for new relation which requires joining between `AudienceRel` and Email table (something like "since" property on [this page](http://orientdb.com/teleporter-configuration/) )

Any suggest?

Best regards...

Comment: Hi, which version are you using?                                                           maybe can help you: http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Teleporter-Home.html

Comment: The version is not important. Version 2.2.x is ok. The link you've provided is just a simple configuration command in the shell. The question is completely clear and I just need a configuration file link which is in the question.